# Codeigniter and Doctrine

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have my project in CodeIgniter 2.1.4 and I have used Doctrine library in my models. My project has been working fine but lately the following error pops up in my log.php

```
mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead
```

My project is big and wanted to ask for help on how to migrate to **mysqli extension** or if there is any other solution. I have seen many similar questions with some solutions here but the problem is that my project is really big and I have immensely depended on doctrine to query my database.

Comment: If you do not have resources to actually migrate to `mysqli` or `PDO`, I suggest you disable deprecation messages in your `php.ini`

Comment: @JovanPerovic Ok I can disable the messages but that wont solve the problem. In the future my project may stop running so I thought of solving this once and for all if possible.

Comment: Well, as long as you keep your PHP version fixed, you won't have an issue :) I know, it does not mean much, but still... :)

Comment: @JovanPerovic Ok. Thank you for the response